# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method for Jetpack Composable

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-jetpack-compose, android-module

I'm creating an Android Library for basic dialogs. Right now, all I have is a `basic-dialogs` module along with the `app` module. I'm calling a composable in the `basic-dialogs` module from the `Activity` in the `app` module, and I keep getting the exception error message below about a `No static method` when I try to run the app. What could be wrong with the code?

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method BasicDialog(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function0;Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function0;Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function2;Landroidx/compose/runtime/Composer;II)V in class Lcom/<domain>/basic_dialogs/BasicDialogKt; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.<domain>.basic_dialogs.BasicDialogKt' appears in /data/app/~~DOqVbMGsnzDWFS7_YdNgtw==/com.<domain>.composedialogs-_5IuirMOFh5F8pL884Urnw==/base.apk!classes2.dex)
```

**Activity**

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            ComposeDialogsTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
                ) {
                    BasicDialog(onDismiss = {  }, onConfirmClick = {  }, title = "Test Dialog", confirmButtonText = "Open") {
                        Text("This is a test dialog.")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**BasicDialog Composable**

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalComposeUiApi::class)
@Composable
fun BasicDialog(
    title: String = "",
    confirmButtonText: String,
    onDismiss: () -> Unit,
    onConfirmClick: () -> Unit,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    Surface(
        shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.medium,
        color = MaterialTheme.colors.surface,
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(4.dp)
    ) {
        Dialog(
            onDismissRequest = onDismiss,
            properties = DialogProperties(
                dismissOnBackPress = true,
                dismissOnClickOutside = true,
                usePlatformDefaultWidth = false
            ),
        ) {
            if (title != "") {
                Text(title)
                Spacer(Modifier.padding(5.dp))
            }

            content()
            Spacer(Modifier.padding(5.dp))
            TextButton(onClick = onDismiss) {
                Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.dialog_cancel), fontSize = 16.sp)
            }
            TextButton(onClick = { onConfirmClick() }) {
                Text(text = confirmButtonText, fontSize = 16.sp)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Project Gradle file**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_version = '1.1.0-beta01'
    }
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.5.31' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**app module Gradle file**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.<domain>.composedialogs"
        minSdk 27
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_version
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.1'
    implementation project(path: ':basic-dialogs')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:$compose_version"
}
```

**basic-dialog module Grade file**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk 27
        targetSdk 32

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles "consumer-rules.pro"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
}
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The following needs to be added to the `basic-dialogs` module's `build.gradle` file:

```
buildFeatures {
    compose true
}
composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_version
}
```

**Entire Gradle file**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk 27
        targetSdk 32

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles "consumer-rules.pro"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_version
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
}
```

Comment: This helped me save lots of time. Thank you

Comment: Thank you sir, you saved my day. Because of missing  buildFeatures {
        compose true
    } line I got this error but now fixed :)

Comment: Everytime i face this problem in my multimodule app and this answer helps me to solve that

Comment: Why do the Android team not provide a sensible error here. Like it's bleeding obvious people will do this and yet here we all are.

Comment: This is needed in a module having Composable as well in addition to main app gradle. - Thanks for the input

Answer (score 6):

Let me hopefully save someone the 3 hours this just cost me. If you are using the Compose BOM in a multi-module project and need an updated version of an individual dependency different to what is specified in the BOM, and your modules also share the BOM, then be very careful sharing dependencies across modules.

In my example I had:

```
    implementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
    api("androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.0-rc01") // Relatively new and needed for date & time pickers
```

in one module, then a load of other modules depending on this one. Some of those modules also specified:

```
implementation(libs.androidx.compose.material3)
```

This caused havoc with the app, where one module was perfectly fine and other unrelated ones were crashing at runtime telling me they didn't know what a TextField was.

Answer (score 4):

Cleaning build, then rebuilding fixed the issue for me.

Comment: absolutely, it does!!

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done using Kotlin DSL way:

```
android {
    buildFeatures.compose = true
    composeOptions.kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.10"
}
```